# Expand function to return error

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a function that returns false for many reasons. Is it possible to also make it throw catchable errors without breaking other code relying on it being true or false?

Or will I have to return arrays or return error resasons and only true on success?

What is the best aproach for this?

Some idea based on Daniel's approach:

__FUNCTION__ should return the functions name

```
$errors = array();
function someFunction(){
    if(ErrorTWOhappened()){
        global $errors[__FUNCTION__] = "ERRORtwo";
        return false;
    }
    if(someOtherError()){
        global $errors[__FUNCTION__] = "someOtherError";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
if(!someFunction())echo $errors['someFunction'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to break backwards compatibility but to provide more information, you can create a second function to log error messages. In a procedual approach, this could look like this:

```
$myFunctionErrors = array();
function myFunctionSetError($error) {
    global $myFunctionErrors;
    $myFunctionsErrors[] = $error;
}

function myFunctionGetErrors() {
    global $myFunctionErrors;
    return $myFunctionErrors;
}
```

And just call `myFunctionSetError('whatever');` inside your existing function. *Note*: `myFunction` is just a prefix, name it after your real function.

*Note also*: You could obviously use the array directly. For better maintainability, however, I recommend you using functions you can modify later on to easily change the logic behind it.

If you prefer an object oriented approach, you can also set up a class for that and prevent possible side-effects regarding the global `$myFunctionErrors` variable.

```
class MyFunctionErrorLogger
{
    protected static $errors = array();

    public function setError($error)
    {
        self::$errors[] = $error;
    }

    public static function getErrors()
    {
        return self::$errors;
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer a "hacked" way, extend the function a little. By adding another function parameter with a `false` default value. Old function calls won't be affected by this but you ca provide this extra parameter in your future calls.

```
function myFunction($myParam, ..., $errorsAsException = false)
{
    // ...
    // Ooops, error case
    if ($errorAsException)
        throw new WhatEverException('errormsg');
    else
        return false;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there no official way to make something like: `return: false;throw "wrong password"` . Your solution should work fine, but I'm hoping there's a less "hacked" way ;)

Comment: No, there isn't. As soon as you return a value, the execution of the function code stops. As soon as you throw an exception, the execution also stops.

Comment: is throwing an exception always treated as false?

Comment: just saw some other idea to "improve" your solution. Will add it to my question, tell me, what you think.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your comment. As soon as you throw an exception, there is no return value. The code execution is stopped and the catch block - if present - is invoked.

Comment: Your edit is pretty much my suggestion #1 but it uses the `$error` variable directly. I'd prefer an interface to set and get errors as it enhances maintainability. After thinking a little, I think I'd take my third suggestion.

Comment: Execution does not stop after "return" in PHP, unfortunately, unless they've fixed that. Just ask anyone who forgot to call `exit` after a conditional redirect.

Comment: Accepted your solution. Although solved my problem by handling all erros within the class by setting $this->error and when a function returns false, $Someobject->return_error(); .